# Is it possible to write one program with three programming languages?

Tags: java, c++, programming-languages, d

Is it possible to make **one** program, written in Java, C++ and D?

Comment: what crap yo keep closing things, you haters

Comment: What is the purpose? Can you not split the program into separate processes and use IPC mechanisms such as pipes, sockets, or shared memory?

Comment: Yes. Seriously though: your question is pretty unspecific, please explain what you want to accomplish.

Comment: well any program. game, video converter, browser.............

Comment: What are you asking ? Are you asking to write a program with different pieces in different languages ? Are you asking to translate source code from one language to another ? Can you explain why you would want to do this ? This might be a really long answer so people would like to make sure what you are asking. What are the constraint for the program ? Should it run under CLR or JVM ? Which OS ? Please explain a little instead of posing a one line question and expecting people to spend some time answering.

Comment: let just say we are making a game. the drawing is done by c++, the shotting and run stuff is done by d and networking is done by java

Comment: @Ramiz: Given that description then, yes, it is possible.  An application or set of application can be broken up into different inter-communicating pieces and each piece can (should, in fact) be developed using the language that's best suited for that purpose.

Comment: @Ramiz, please read http://tinyurl.com/so-hints - that might explain why your questions keep getting closed.

Comment: @David, the cost at going multi-process is so high, that it usually in  itself prohibits doing things in this way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you want to write, say, a game that compiles both in Java, C++ and D ? No can do. But you can e.g. create a library (in C) with common logic and use that from Java (via JNI), C++ and D.

Still, there's not much point in doing so except if you need to target platform where you don't have influence on the environment (like an embedded system or something like iOS or Android).

Comment: A digression re your first statement: MAYBE it's possible. "Polyglot programs" are those written in multiple languages, e.g. http://ideology.com.au/polyglot/ which is a single file which can be compiled/interpreted as Cobol, Pascal, Fortran, C, PostScript, Shell script, x86 assembler, and Perl. See also http://www.nyx.net/~gthompso/poly/polyglot.htm . Getting from a 'hello world' type program to a full game might be a bit more of a challenge though. :)

Comment: I know that in theory it's possible, which is why I answered "Yes" (which was more more of a joke), but that in practice only a hacker looking for a fun challenge would even try. But thanks for the links :-)

Answer (score 1):

You can certainly interface Java and C++ using JNI.

I don't see anything about interfacing D to other languages.

You can interface any language that can remote using a commonly understood protocol: raw sockets, HTTP, etc.  The two participants can be in any language, as long as they can agree on the protocol.

The lines of "one program" get a little blurry then.

Answer (score 0):

If i understood your question correctly, using JNI(Java native interface) you can link c++ code with Java code.
You can get some info at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Native_Interface